# Why won't my dodgeCount variable work?

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I wrote a fairly simple game in ruby, where you are a space shuttle and you have to dodge a few meteorites. I decided to put in a dodge counter, but the alert message isn't showing the actual score. Here's the code:

```
@dodgeCount = 0
require 'gosu'

class  MyGame < Gosu::Window
  def initialize
    super(600, 400, false)
    @player1 = Player.new(self)
    @balls = 3.times.map {Ball.new(self)} 
    @running = true
  end

  def update
    if @running
      if button_down? Gosu::Button::KbLeft
        @player1.move_left
      end

      if button_down? Gosu::Button::KbRight
        @player1.move_right
      end

      if button_down? Gosu::Button::KbUp
        @player1.move_up
      end

      if button_down? Gosu::Button::KbDown
        @player1.move_down
      end

      @balls.each {|ball| ball.update} 

      if @player1.hit_by? @balls
        stop_game!
        alert "Your score is " + @dodgeCount.to_s
      end
    else
      #the game is now stopped
      if button_down? Gosu::Button::KbEscape
        restart_game
      end
    end
  end

  def draw
    @player1.draw
    @balls.each {|ball| ball.draw}
  end

  def stop_game!
    @running = false
  end

  def restart_game
    @running = true
    @balls.each {|ball| ball.reset!}
  end
end

class Player
  def initialize(game_window)
    @game_window = game_window
    @icon = Gosu::Image.new(@game_window, "gosu/player1.png", true)
    @x = 50
    @y = 330
  end

  def draw
    @icon.draw(@x, @y, 1)
  end

  def move_left
    if @x < 0
      @x = 0
    else
      @x = @x - 10
    end
  end

  def move_right
    if @x > (@game_window.width - 75)
      @x = @game_window.width - 75
    else
      @x = @x + 10
    end
  end

  def move_up
    if @y < 0
      @y = 0
    else
      @y = @y - 10
    end
  end

  def move_down
    if @y > (@game_window.height - 75)
      @y = @game_window.height - 75
    else
      @y = @y + 10
    end
  end

  def hit_by? (balls)
    balls.any? {|ball| Gosu::distance(@x, @y, ball.x, ball.y) < 50}
  end
end

class Ball
  def initialize(game_window)
    @game_window = game_window
    @icon = Gosu::Image.new(@game_window, "gosu/asteroid.png", true)
    reset!
  end

  def update
    if @y > @game_window.height
      reset!
      @dodgeCount = @dodgeCount + 1
    else
      @y = @y + 10
    end
  end

  def draw
    @icon.draw(@x, @y, 2)
  end

  def x
    @x
  end

  def y 
    @y
  end

  def reset!
    @y = 0
    @x = rand(@game_window.width)
  end

end

 window = MyGame.new
 window.show
```

Comment: show us the error please if you have any?

Comment: thats what i don't get. There's no error, it's just that the score won't show up

Comment: where is show method defined?, i cannot see any method that is being invoked, to alter the value of `@dodgeCount` instance variable in calling show method.

Answer (score 0):

The `@dodgeCount` variable that appears to be tracking the score is in class `Ball`, whilst you are using `alert` to display another (otherwise unused) variable in class `MyGame`. When Ruby sees an instance variable name (beginning with `@`), it will create that instance variable for you automatically if it doesn't already exist, so you end up with a `nil` value for the score, which then ends up displaying as `""` (because `nil.to_s == ""`).

There is also the problem that you have three balls, and each one will track the score separately.

You will be better off tracking the score in the same `MyGame` class where you want to display it. The easiest thing to do is move some of the code from `Ball#update` to `MyGame#update`.

You will need to initialise and re-set the score with

```
@dodgeCount = 0
```

In `MyGame#initialize` and `MyGame#restart_game`

Where you currently have in `MyGame#update`, `@balls.each {|ball| ball.update}` add code to detect dodges, and track the score:

```
@balls.each do |ball| 
  ball.update
  if ball.y > height
    ball.reset!
    @dodgeCount = @dodgeCount + 1
  end
end
```

And `Ball#update` is simplified:

```
def update
  @y = @y + 10
end
```

I hope this works for you, I don't have a copy of `gosu` available to check in detail.